# Webpack dynamic import causing react remount

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-apollo

Versions

webpack 4.1.1, react 16.3.1, apollo-boost 0.1.4 (apollo-client 2.2.8)

See below for code. Essentially what I have found is that whenever I try to load my component in the render function, componentDidMount is being called forever. removing the reference to `.default` and just rendering null resolves the issue, moving the reference to `.default` to the render method does not. How can I use the dynamic imports here alongside react correctly? Note that before I had the react-apollo query component for managing state this worked fine. What do I need to do to combine these 3 tools to actually cooperate? After 4-5 hours on the same issue I've made no progress.

```
const RouterContainer = () => (
  <Query
    query={gql`
      {
        currentRoute @client
        routeArgs @client
      }
    `}
  >{({ data }) => <Router {...data} />}</Query>
);

class Router extends React.Component {
  state = {
    component: null,
    page: '',
  }
  fetchComponent = () => {
    import('./MyComponent).then(Component => {
      this.setState({ Component: Component.default });
    });
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.page !== nextProps.currentRoute) {
      return { page: nextProps.currentRoute };
    }
    return null;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // Being run infinitely. Why???
    // this.fetchComponent();
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.Component ? <this.state.Component /> : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do the dynamic import? Why not just import it and use it?

Comment: Totally forgot to post my answer earlier. Unrelated problem that I had misdiagnosed. The dynamic import was largely a proof of concept idea I was working with

Comment: You should just remove the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant to put this up months ago and it slipped my mind apparently. Problem ended up being unrelated to this and an incomplete refactor I did that resulted in an infinite react tree (child rendered parent)